# Changing the value of a variable that is a parameter in the parent scope

Tags: php, scope, parent-child

Is there any way to change the value of a parameter in the parent scope without passing it by reference to the child scope? I'd like to do something like this:

```
function foo($x = 5)
{
    bar();
    echo $x;  // Ideally should output 6
}

function bar()
{
    $x = 6;
}

foo();
```

In the scope of bar, I can get the value of $x by using debug_backtrace() or ReflectionFunction::getParameters, but I can't get a reference to $x!! Can this be done? I don't care if the solution is kind of a hack.

(To reiterate, I KNOW that I could just pass $x by reference to bar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `foo()` is not the parent scope of `bar()` - both functions exist in the global scope and the body of each function has it's own local scope.

The short answer to the question is as follows: *no*. Two alternatives:

Just assign the return value of `bar()` to the local variable `$x':

```
function foo($x = 5) {
    $x = bar();
    echo $x;  // Ideally should output 6
}
function bar() {
    return 6;
}
foo();
```

Encapsulate the logic of `bar()` into an external file (instead of a function) and `include` it:

bar.php:

```
<?php
 $x = 6;
```

foo.php

```
<?php
 function foo($x = 5) {
   include 'bar.php';
   echo $x;  // outputs '6'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it using globals: http://no.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Oh yeah I should mention, I don't want to use globals either.

Comment: @Chiraag Mundhe Taking the limitations you have set into account I would say it's not possible.

Comment: Ok thanks. Was just wondering if there was some obscure feature of the language that could be exploited here.

Answer (score 0):

php has global variables.  you can access a global from within a function by using the `global` keyword, or by using the `$GLOBALS` array directly.

Both techniques are described on the [Variable Scope page of PHP's Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
function bar()
{
    global $x;

    $x = 6;
}
```